# Can't access to injected AngularJS services within a function in a controller

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, angularjs

Cannot access to $scope and Food inside destroy function.

```
foodProject.controller('FoodsCtrl', function($scope, Food) {

    $scope.foods = Food.index();
    $scope.destroy = function(food){
        debugger;
        console.log(Food, $scope);
        food.$destroy();
    };
});
```

The local scope variables are only

food: Resource

this: $get.e.$new.a

I can't find $scope and Food

http://jsfiddle.net/fW2EA/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/wizztjh/fW2EA/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this line in your destroy function (it is missing from your fiddle):

```
console.log(Food, $scope);
```

Then in your debugger, check the Closure section of Scope Variables (I was using Chrome), when stopped on your break point. `Food` and `$scope` are in there (as one would expect!).

`this` in the context of the destroy function is a new scope within the ng-repeat so is not the same as `$scope`, although both are scopes.

Comment: I found out if added console.log(Food, $scope); I can access to Food , if I dont use the food. At the debugger I cant acccess to Food service. Angular is so magical ......

Answer (score 1):

Within your function, `this` is the scope, e.g. `this.foods`.

I believe if you want `Food` to be accessible add it to the scope, i.e., `$scope.Food = Food;`.

I'm still a noob and am not sure if adding `Food` to `$scope` is the right thing to do.

Comment: somehow angular will know whether you use the Food Service anot. If you dont use it, it won't initialize it ..... omg ...

Comment: If you're confused about dependency injection (indeed, it does seem like magic :-] ), give this a read: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: @wizztjh OMG, I was like WTF? Why injected dependencies doesn't appear when I stop using debugger? ... Thanks!